# How to query XML elements from a local XML file in Internet Explorer using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I am building a single HTML page for use in a touch-screen kiosk. I have an external XML file named `data.xml` which resides in the same directory as my HTML page. I was able to use jQuery to load the external XML file, parse it and build some HTML dynamically on page load without any problems in Firefox and Chrome. **But then I tried it in Internet Explorer...**

The XML document loads just fine using the $.ajax() function. I did an `alert(xmlDoc.text())` and it showed all the text contents of the XML document. So that is not the problem.

I did some searching and found [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811672/jquery-get-post-not-working-on-ie-7-or-8-works-fine-in-ff/904586#answer-812141) which gives a solution to the problem IF you're serving the XML from a web server. It basically states that the following HTTP HEADER is needed in order for Internet Explorer to treat the xml string as xml.

`content-type:application/xml;charset=utf-8`

This HTML page needs to just run as a standalone page inside Internet Explorer. **We will not have a web server** running on the kiosk machine.

My question is whether there is any way to specify the correct content-type when loading a local resource in jQuery?

Here's the relevant ajax code I am working with...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.xml',
  async : false,
  success : function(response) {
    xml = $(response);
  }
});

// Following line works in Firefox/Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer
var firstItemText = $("item:first", xml).text();
```

**EDIT: I have added an error handling function on the ajax request like so...**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.xml',
  async : false,
  dataType : "xml",
  success : function(response) {
    xml = $(response);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Data Could Not Be Loaded - '+ textStatus);
  }
});
```

This function is firing in Internet Explorer and the resulting message is:

`Data Could Not Be Loaded: - parsererror`

I checked my XML document with several online XML validator tools and it has no errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing I managed to make it work.

The problem is when you are loading XML files locally, the data received by Internet Explorer is plain-text, not text/xml.

The solution is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.xml',
async : false,
dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
success : function(response) 
{
    if (typeof response == "string") 
    {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(response);
    } 
    else 
        xml = $(response);
    },

error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
    alert('Data Could Not Be Loaded - '+ textStatus);
}
});

var firstItemText = $("item:first", xml).text();
```

You can see the full explanation in this link:

http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

I'm glad if I helped.

Comment: That hit the nail on the head! Thanks Philipe!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your content type to:

```
content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

And dont forget to add this line in your XML file (must be the first line)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Where do you suggest I change the content-type? I am not serving the XML file from a web server.  I will try the XML declaration.

Comment: I added the XML declaration and I get the same results.