# jquery post doesn't work in ie

Tags: jquery, post

My jquery code works in ff, chrome, opera, safari but it doesn't work in ie. My data i am reciving is in html format. What I have to change?

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='dishType']").change( function() {
    var dishType = $(this).val();
    $.post('index.py/ingredients', { 'q' : dishType}, function(data) { $('.ingredients').html(data)});
});
```

Comment: Well, what's the problem? How does it not work under IE?

Comment: might won't to edit your question, does the event actually get fired?.

Comment: @Gareth Davis: it does in all browsers but in ie seems it doesn't

Comment: I have tried your snippet in IE6, it works as intended. Are you sure there are no other errors on the page? Does it work if you replace you $.post with an alert?

Comment: i think there isn't any errors - looks fine in firebug
if i change $.post to alert 'index.py/ingredients' popup as it should

Comment: could be an issue with something else on the page. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811672/jquery-get-post-not-working-on-ie-7-or-8-works-fine-in-ff

Answer (score 3):

The "change" event will only fire in IE if you click somewhere outside of radiobutton. To fix this you should also listen for "click" events.

Comment: in which IE does this happen? Seems to fire if I click on the input or associated label in IE8 and IE7: http://jsbin.com/efapi4

Comment: When I changed my example to use an earlier version of jQuery (1.2.6 or 1.3.2) it works as you described. Looks like they've fixed this(introduced a workaround) in 1.4.4

Comment: i change "change" event to "click" event but still doesn't work.
it doesn't work in any of ie browsers

Comment: @Inrbob, you're right, I experienced this problem with an earlier version of jQuery. Didn't know they got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It might not actually be the AJAX call.

Have you checked for any trailing `,` or other syntax errors (try jslint) IE is very strict on the syntax and it maybe that which is the issue rather than the actual AJAX call it's self.

Having said that it could just be that IE won't fire a 'change' event on simply changing the value of a radio button, it waits for it to lose focus (blur). See quirksmode documentation on the [change event](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html). Seem to remember the work around is to listen to click instead of 'change'.

Comment: is there any add-on for ie like firebug for ff that i could see ajax calls

Comment: IE Developer Toolbar: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535 and Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: In ie7 + ie8 just press F12 the developer tools are should just work. IE6 either use FireBug lite or fiddler (see @Alisey's comment). if all else fails alert('hello mum') call help too.

Comment: where i can see in ie developer toolbar if post was made

Comment: I was thinking of just putting a break point in just to check if the event handler is actually being run.

Answer (score 0):

can you try removing the quotes out of the q. You dont need to add it.. IE might be messing that up.. not sure.. but something worth trying..

And can you try alerting in the callback function to see if you are actually getting a response.

hope that helps